# Who is the second guard?

Tags: v-for-vendetta

When Evey is in her cell in *V for Vendetta*, at some point there's a scene when two men drag her along the corridor:

[image]

But when she is free, she learns that it was all V's doing. He said he did it alone, but at least in the above instance there's a second person involved. And yet, it's clear from the entire movie that V is working completely alone.

Is that second guard a blooper, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is Valerie not Evey. Evey is imagining the scene and/or flashbacks based on Valerie's secret journal, which Evey "found" and is reading.

Here's the scene:

Comment: You're absolutely right! Thanks. All those stories got confusing.

Comment: @madmada no problem. Try to flesh out any answer, as single sentence ones tend to get down voted.